# Simplest Way to Effect a Horizontal Shift of the Output in a Verse Environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, output, verse

Consider the following code which produces the illustrated 4-line stanza:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \large
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \vskip 25pt
    
    \begin{verse}
    \begin{Large}
    {\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
    This is a line in a stanza \\
    This is a line in a stanza \\
    This is a line in a stanza.} \par}
    \end{Large}
    \end{verse}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to be able to shift the entire stanza horizontally to the right, say 50pt.

However, putting either `\hskip 50pt` or `\hspace*{50pt}` immediately prior to `\begin{verse}` increases (surprisingly) only the vertical placement of the stanza.

QUESTION: Can someone describe the simplest way to effect a horizontal shift of the stanza?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\leftskip 50pt` upon entering the `verse` environment.

Also, to my knowledge, `\Large` is a declaration, not an environment.  It will end all by itself at the end of the verse, because the scope of the verse closes at that point.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \large
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \vskip 25pt
    
    \begin{verse}
    \leftskip 50pt
    \Large
    {\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
    This is a line in a stanza \\
    This is a line in a stanza \\
    This is a line in a stanza.} \par}
    \end{verse}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The length used for the indentation of verses is `\leftmargini`, according to the documentation. So we can use `\addtolength\leftmargini}{shift length}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\large
\lipsum[1]

\vskip 25pt

\begin{verse}
\begin{Large}
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza.} \par}
\end{Large}
\end{verse}

\addtolength{\leftmargini}{50pt}
\begin{verse}
\begin{Large}
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza.} \par}
\end{Large}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `verse` package provides for an optional length argument to the `verse` environment. If this is set to the average length of a line of verse then the whole verse will be centered with respect to the textwidth. You can use this for shifting the stanzas.

```
% verseprob2.tex  SE 597751
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{\Large \texttt{This is a line in the stanza}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\large
\lipsum[1]

\vskip 25pt

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\Large
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza.} \par}
\end{verse}

But without the optional length argument:

\begin{verse}%[\versewidth]
\Large
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza.} \par}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

The length `versewidth` is part of the package.

[image]